# Routing ADFS through Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, adfs, azure-application-gateway

I've checked with other answers on other questions, but none of lead to a solution.

We have two ADFS Proxies onsite that hosts our Salesforce SSO. Currently, that path is as follows:
**login.domain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon**

This URL currently routes to an HAProxy 2.6 Enterprise reverse proxy, which load balances over those two ADFS proxies. This setup works well, but we're looking to migrate most on-premise systems to Azure native solutions.

I have an Azure Application Gateway configured that will handle our RDS and NGINX traffic, but I am having trouble routing the above traffic successfully. The problem is that the HTTPS Custom Probe is detecting an HTTP 404 response, but using cURL or Postman results in expected responses.

#### Backend pool

- **Name**: adfs-prod
- **Backend targets**: x.x.x.x

#### Backend setting

- **Backend settings name**: login.domain.com
- **Backend protocol**: HTTPS
- **Backend port**: 443
- **Trusted Root**:
- **Cookie affinity**: false
- **Connection draining**: false
- **Request time-out**: 20 seconds
- **Override backend path**: *blank*

#### Listener

- **Listener name**: login.domain.com
- **Frontend IP**: Public
- **Protocol**: HTTPS
- **Port**: 443
- **Certificate**:
- **Renew or edit selected certificate**: false
- **Enable SSL Profile**: false
- **Listener type**: Multi site
- **Host type**: Single
- **Host name**: login.domain.com

#### Health Probe

- **Name**: login.domain.com
- **Pick hostname from backend settings**: Yes
- **Pick port from backend settings**: Yes
- **Path**: /adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon
- **Use probe matching conditions**: Yes
- **HTTP response status match**: 200-399

As mentioned above, the results from Postman are fine. Here's what I would expect Azure Application Gateway to report:

***Testing Root URL***
login.domain.com => GET HTTP/1.1 => HTTP 404

***Testing with ADFS Path***
login.domain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon => GET HTTP/1.1 => HTTP 200

But as it stands based on the response, it seems that the probe is not taking the path into account.

I have tried recreating it several times, have verified that the IP is allowed in the firewalls, and tried defining the hostname in the probe as well.

Also, please keep in-mind that some NGINX probes that we have are checking heartbeat paths on other domains and are functioning perfectly:
**fakename.domain.com/api/v1/heartbeat => GET HTTP/1.1 => HTTP 200**

Does anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: Could you please include backend setting, backend pool and listener to know more in detail.

Comment: @Imran - Thank you for the response. I have modified the question with your requested information.

Answer (score 0):

> Received invalid status code: 404 in the backend server’s HTTP response. As per the health probe configuration, 200-399 is the acceptable status code. Either modify probe configuration or resolve backend issues. To learn more visit -https://aka.ms/StatusCodeMismatch.

The `404` error occurs due to multiple reasons, to resolve the error check the below:

- Check if you have any UDR associated with your application gateway. Using UDRs on the Application Gateway subnet might result in incorrect health-probe or traffic-routing behavior.

  So, if you have a UDR, validate that it is matching one of the recommended setup.
  [Azure Application Gateway infrastructure configuration | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-infrastructure#supported-user-defined-routes)

Created ***backend setting*** like below:

[image]

Make sure in backend setting `override with new host name` and `pick hostname from backend target` like below:

[image]

***Listener***:

[image]

In healthy probe If the backend pool is set up with just IPs or `x.AzureWebsites.net` , then the probes may have issues. but if the server expects a specific hostname in the request, then the probe must not pass the wrong hostname nor an IP. In these scenarios, using `PickHostnameFromBackend` in the probe configuration would fail.

To resolve this issue, specify the hostname directly for the probe configuration. Alternatively, change the backend pool to be hostname that the backend expects.

[image]

You can change the HTTP response status match to `200-499` to allow for a wider range of response codes.

Check the backend health pool are in health state like below:

[image]

For the Azure Application Gateway, you may enable diagnostic logging to collect more detailed information about the requests and responses. The logs may offer understanding of the problem and assist in determining the reason for the 404 error.

- Additionally, check If the VNet has custom DNS and that server cannot resolve the backend pool name(s), then probes will fail. Naturally, traffic to the backend would also fail if we cannot resolve the names.
- When the Application gateway has NSGs blocking the probe ports.
  V1 SKU: Ports 65503-65534
  V2 SKU: Ports 65200-65535

[Azure Application Gateway infrastructure configuration | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-infrastructure#network-security-groups)